# The tag 'XXX' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:YYY'

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have implemented a converter to convert Int32 to String to be able to binding a property to a textBox.

I implement this converter in the namespace MyApp.Converters and it is called Int32ToStringConverter.

Then, in my axml I add the reference to my converter as follow:

```
<Window x:Class="MusicaDB.Views.PrincipalView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        **xmlns:converter="clr-namesapce:MyApp.Converters, aseembly=MyApp**">
```

Later, in windows.Resources I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <**converter:Int32ToStringConverter** x:Key="Int32ToStringConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

I get the error that the tag Int32ToString converter does not exist in the namespace MyApp.Converters,assembly=MyApp.

I have the project in the local hard drive, in the project properties, the destination .NET is framework 4.0, not framework 4.0 client profile and I try to clear the solution and recompile but the problem persists.

Mainly, this is the two solutions that I always find, but don't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Three fixes to make here:

1. No spaces -> `xmlns:converter="clr-namesapce:MyApp.Converters,aseembly=MyApp"`
2. No misspellings -> `xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters,assembly=MyApp"`
3. Right delimiters -> `xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters;assembly=MyApp"`

From the [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx):

> Note that the character separating the **clr-namespace** token from its value is a colon (:) whereas the character separating the **assembly** token from its value is an equals sign (=). The character to use between these two tokens is a semicolon. Also, do not include any whitespace anywhere in the declaration.

Comment: reference link is gone!

Comment: @WaldoAlvarez: It's not, that's just MSDN using a stupid default, if you see "This topic is no longer available", select a previous version from the "Other Versions" dropdown.

Comment: ahh ok thanks, better provide direct link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @WaldoAlvarez: Well, i did not foresee MSDN handling versions like this, so all links in all my questions are generic without version numbers. Also most of those articles apply perfectly fine to the newest version, it's just a matter of them reviewing them and making the respective entry in the database.

Comment: Already doing this, the issue persists. -- It only happens for some controls, and they're all using the exact same markup.  How do we force it to regenerate the `.g.cs` files?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: Usually building the solution should be enough. You can try cleaning and rebuilding. Did you make sure the types you use sufficiently visible (i.e. not private or internal when from another assembly)? Also, for referencing the current assembly it's `[...];assembly=`.

Comment: My issue was solved by adding the assemby value. Thanks for pointing me in the right way.

Answer (score 28):

Another possible solution to this problem is that you're not using the same version of .Net in your project and your library.

Comment: This is very helpful-- I had my syntax right, but forgot to set the framework version for the new assembly I was referencing. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? More details

Comment: Would love to mark this as the answer. Since my code was generated, it was not wrong and this answer solved my problem

Comment: My solution ended up being the opposite of this.  I wasn't specifying assembly before, but now I am, and the issue is fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: This was sort of my issue, only the binary in question throwing the xaml errors had a dependency on a particular version of System.Windows.Interactivity which was incorrect in my project.

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner!

Answer (score 13):

I am exploring as to why this is happening, but if your converter is in the main assembly, removing the assembly= from your xmlns:converters tag should remove that build error.

Answer (score 5):

For the record ...
I've face a similar problem and if I removed the ";assembly=X" part from the XAML it worked fine

But don't really understand the reason.

As suggested in this blog: 
http://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/fix-the-tag-xxx-does-not-exist-in-xml-namespace-clr-namespaceyyy/#comment-7761

Comment: Apparently, if it's in the same assembly, don't put it.  If it's not, then do put it.

Answer (score 4):

I see two possible causes.  The first is that you misspelled "assembly" as "aseembly" in the first starred line.  Changing the spelling might be enough.  The second possibility is that you haven't added MyApp.dll to your project references, which appear like this

[image]

in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

All answers are right. And after trying all of them and you cannot configure why its happening, everything seems alright, Please restart the Visual studio.

That worked for me after wasting almost 1 hour. I found everything ok, but restarted the VS with administration.

Comment: I literally was trying to figure out what was going on for like about 3 HOURS!! Your suggestion to restart VS did the trick!!

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

use the assemble tag only if it is in another project.
other wise use just namespace tag alone.
For me this fixed the issue

Comment: This was my issue too.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, I had the same problem with `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<mydefaultnamespace>"`.
    I solved this changing the order of the includes. I put it first and all was solved.
    A strange behaviour, but this was my workaround that I found in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, **the assembly which contained the namespace was not physically there**.

I checked the references of the assembly that had the build error and looked at the properties of the referenced assembly in question.

I navigated to the path and discovered the assembly was indeed missing (*which I realised was my own doing*), giving rise to the misleading error.

Answer (score 1):

There is one very obscure case when you get this error - if you're using `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` and you upgrade to Windows 10 anniversary edition, or as it turns out the Creator edition too.

Even if this isn't what happens to you make sure the library containing the component that cannot be found can be fully compiled. Look in the error list (not the grid but the Output console) for any clues.

In my case I was using `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` as part of an HTML editor and it was unregistered somehow (in the GAC).

The following article explains with screenshots:

https://techninotes.blogspot.com/2016/08/fixing-cannot-find-wrapper-assembly-for.html#comment-form

In short I had to run a Visual Studio command prompt (as admin) run these commands:

```
cd C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.mshtml\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
regasm Microsoft.mshtml.dll
```

I did say obscure :-) The important point is to read the errors that may be buried amongst all your warnings because there might be an important clue.

This can be especially confusing if an Operating system update suddenly breaks your project.

Comment: Looks like it's EVERY Windows feature update. Happened again to me just now.

Comment: I think for 2019 the 'Visual Studio Command Prompt' has gone away and it's now `Developer Powershell for VS2019` (make sure to run as admin).

Answer (score 0):

I was temporarily replacing a NuGet dll with a local one when this happened. Turned out the assembly was not the same version as the one I was replacing. I built my assembly with the correct version and it worked.