# Missing assembly reference when adding converter

Tags: c#

In App.xaml when i tried to add converter then it says `you are missing assembly reference`

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <converter:RssTextTrimmer xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:sdkRSSReaderCS"
        x:Key="RssTextTrimmer" />
    <converter:ImageFromRssText xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:sdkRSSReaderCS"
        x:Key="ImageFromRssText" />

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Maybe duplicated... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151366/the-tag-xxx-does-not-exist-in-xml-namespace-clr-namespaceyyy

Comment: I think that you might have to define your references in whatever the root tag of your xaml file is

Comment: There is a missing `>` on the second `converter`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Make sure you have build it at least once, without compiler errors and if it is in another assembly make sure you supply that parameter: `xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:sdkRSSReaderCS;assembly=MyOtherAssembly;"`

Comment: How to define reference in  root tag of my xaml file  can anyone elaborate